# how many ways to choose 2 disjoint subsets of a given set

Tags: combinatorics

> A,B $\subset$  {1,2,...,n} .
>   how many ways are there to choose A and B : A $\cap$ B = $\phi$

I tried to tackle this using say there are $2^n$ - $ 2^{n-1} $ subsets containing 1 for example and $2^{n-1}$ subsets that don't so I could multiply them however I think I'm not covering all cases here..

any ideas?

Comment: Why did you delete the previous question? Will you do it again now?

Comment: @MariaMazur because I found a different question quite the same as mine so I avoided duplicating posts

Comment: Can you show it

Comment: Why did you mention set $C$?  What relevance does it have to your question?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig there is more to the question where C comes into play

Comment: @MariaMazur
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/254210/using-the-pigeonhole-principle-to-prove-there-is-at-least-two-groups-of-people-w?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Notice that if subsets $A$ and $B$ are disjoint and $i \in \{1, 2, 3, \ldots, n\}$, then exactly one of the following is true:  $i \in A$, $i \in B$, $i \in (A \cup B)^C$.

Comment: so i is either in A , B or neither of A and B , 3 totally, so $3^n$?

Comment: Do you consider $A = \{1\}$, $B = \{2\}$ different from $A = \{2\}$, $B = \{1\}$? If not, then you should divide by $2$.

Comment: @AustinMohr A and B are considered different so the answer is yes

Comment: @lidor718 In that case, you are correct.

Comment: A clarification:  If $A$ and $B$ were considered to be indistinguishable, the answer would be $\frac{3^n + 1}{2}$ since each choice would be counted twice except the one in which $A = B = \emptyset$.